# Spring 4 and Hibernate 4 Session error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, session

On My Spring MVC and hibernate web project what is java base cofiguration, it's generate table from Entity class happly but when i am trying to generate a list of data from my post table but i gate a error about getCurrent Session......

My Entity Class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="post")
public class Post{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

@Column(nullable = false)
String title;

@Column(nullable = false)
@Type(type="text")
String body;

@Column(nullable = true)
String feature_image;

@Column(nullable = true)
int active_status = 1;

 }
```

Dao:

```
@Repository
public class TestDao {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactoryBean;

private Session getCurrentSession() {
    return sessionFactoryBean.getCurrentSession();
}


@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Post> listProduct() {
    return (List<Post>) 
   getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Post.class).list();
  }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class TestService{

@Autowired
private TestDao testDao;

public List<Post> postList(){
return testDao.listProduct();
 }
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

@Autowired
TestService testService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(ModelMap map) {

    List<Post> results = testService.postList();
    Post lastPost=null;
    if(!results.isEmpty()){
        Collections.reverse(results);
        lastPost = results.get(0);
        results.remove(0);
    }
    map.addAttribute("lastPost",lastPost);
    map.addAttribute("postList",results);
    return "home";
  }
}
```

Configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
public class AppDataSourceConfig {

@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();     
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?useSSL=false");
    dataSource.setUsername("root");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");

    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new 
    LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.imran.model");
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(hibProperties());
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}

private Properties hibProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put("hibernate.dialect", 
    "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
    properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto","update");
    return properties;  
  }

@Bean
public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new 
    HibernateTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory().getObject());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

And finally error:

```
   Mar 04, 2018 10:28:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve 
  invoke
  SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path 
    [/BlogSolutionUsingSpringHibernateWithClassLevelConfig] threw exception 
     [Request processing failed; nested exception is 
      org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-
     synchronized 
      Session for current thread] with root cause
      org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-
       synchronized Session for current thread at
```

org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSes
            sionContext.java:134)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.imran.dao.TestDao.getCurrentSession(TestDao.java:21)
    at com.imran.dao.TestDao.listProduct(TestDao.java:27)
    at com.imran.service.TestService.postList(TestService.java:23)
    at com.imran.controller.HomeController.index(HomeController.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:209)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:102)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:871)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:991)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:870)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:855)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:673)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0):

Adding @EnableTransactionManagement on your class should fix your problem